# Children's book about a man fighting his future-self to prevent the end of the world

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

It was part of a long series written by numerous unnamed writers. In one of the books, the protagonist is fighting a fat old man who lives in a motorized chair, who is a wealthy CEO, and is bringing about the end of the world. At some point, he discovers that his enemy is his own time-travelled self.

I would have picked it up at the Hermitage branch of the Nashville Public Library when I was a child sometime between 2003 and 2010.

Answer (score 6):

Potential match: [Johnny and the Bomb,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_and_the_Bomb) by Terry Pratchett. This is a part of a trilogy written by Pratchett, rather than numerous different authors, but there was also a [TV adaption](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0498319/plotsummary). It was first **published in 2007**, so it fits within the specified time period.

> The protagonist, Johnny, is not fighting *his* future self, but the future self of his friend, Stephen (known as 'Wobbler').

The antagonist does indeed become a wealthy CEO in a motorised wheelchair.

[image: Johnny and the bomb]

Comment: sounds like the thing i read might have been a parody of this